# Vim+ctrlP : disable MRU sorting in buffers list

Tags: vim, ctrlp

in Vim, I use CtrlP to switch between my open files. But the displayed list of buffers (in the tab `<buffers>`) is sorted with the most recently used at the bottom.

I would like to disable this sort, and keep my buffers list in the same order I opened them, but I couldn't find any options to do it : is it possible to do so ?

Here's my ctrlP config :

```
map <F1> :CtrlPBuffer<CR> 
let g:ctrlp_switch_buffer = 'Et' "If already opened, jump to it
let g:ctrlp_show_hidden = 1 "Show hidden files and directories
let g:ctrlp_match_current_file = 1 "Show current file in results
let g:ctrlp_follow_symlinks = 1 "Follow symbolic links
```

Thanks in advance for any help.